# Running Android SU command in C

Tags: android, command-line, android-ndk

I want to use SU to launch a command to obtain information about an android phone

```
strcpy(command, "getprop| grep ro.build.display.id")
system(command);
```

However this only works when I am in non root. When I am in root, it does not return anything.
I have also tried using the full path for the command but it isn't working as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue. Apparently running `system()` command in su can only be done in /system/bin and not in /data/local/tmp.